# Plot histogram for data coming from different data.frames?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Is it possible to plot, in the same plot, histograms for data coming from two different `data.frames` in `ggplot`?

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901330/multiple-histograms-with-ggplot2-position) provides the right plots (in terms of the looks); however, it mandates that the data is combined in one `data.frame`. This is quite tough for me as the `data.frame`s have many columns which are different, and a straightforward `rbind()` does not work

Comment: If `rbind` would solve your problem, you may want to use the `rbindlist` function from the `data.table` package, which has an option (`fill` and `use.names`) to just fill in `NA` for any columns that don't overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a single set of x/y coordinates that you are plotting at a time?  If so, you could just create a dataframe that has just the data for those two columns, plus the "fill" column as is used in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600390/creating-density-plots-from-two-different-data-frames-using-ggplot2)  works for me