# List of ggplot density plots across datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several data-sets which are simple transformations of one another, e.g.

```
iris0 <- iris ; iris1 <- iris; iris2 <- iris
iris1[,1:4] <- sqrt(iris0[,1:4])
iris2[,1:4] <- log(iris0[,1:4])
```

I want to visualise how the densities of distributions of each attribute are affected by transformations, using density plots in ggplot2.

I could use code of the following kind:

```
ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x=Attr), fill="red", data=vec_from_dataset1, alpha=.5) + geom_density(aes(x=Attr), fill="blue", data=vec_from_dataset2, alpha=.5)
```

or, for example, bind the attributes together and then consider them as one dataset. What is the best, cleanest/most efficient way of (using Map probably) to generate a list of density plots, where `iris0` is compared to each other dataset (`iris1`and `iris2`), across each numerical attribute i.e. columns 1-4? (So in this case, there would be 4*2 = 8 total density plots.)

(I should clarify--no package except base R+ggplot2 please, dplyr if absolutely necessary)

Edit:

Based on the top answer here: [Creating density plots from two different data-frames using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600390/creating-density-plots-from-two-different-data-frames-using-ggplot2), I had the following go:

```
combs = expand.grid(Attributes=names(X),Datasets=c("iris1","iris2"))
plots <- 
  Map(function(.x, .y, ds2) {
    ggplot(data=iris0, aes(x=.x)) +
      geom_density(fill="red") +
      geom_density(data=get(ds2), fill="purple") +
      xlab(.y) + ggtitle(label=paste0("Density plot for the ",.y))
  }, X[names(X)], names(X), as.character(combs[[2]]))
```

But the output is just the density from the first dataset for each attribute (`iris0`), filled in purple. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach leveraging `rbindlist()` from package data.table that gives you a list of `ggplot` objects you can print or do whatever with downstream.

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3

iris0 <- iris ; iris1 <- iris; iris2 <- iris
iris1[,1:4] <- sqrt(iris0[,1:4])
iris2[,1:4] <- log(iris0[,1:4])


dt <- rbindlist(list(iris0 = iris0, iris1 = iris1, iris2 = iris2), idcol = TRUE)

plot_list <- expand.grid(dat = c("iris1", "iris2"), 
                         var = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

zz <- lapply(1:nrow(plot_list), function(i) {
  plot_dat <- dt[.id %in% c("iris0", plot_list[i, "dat"]), c(".id", plot_list[i, "var"]), with = FALSE]

  plot_names <- names(plot_dat)

  ggplot(plot_dat, aes_string(x = plot_names[[2]], fill = plot_names[[1]])) +
    geom_density(alpha = .5) +
    scale_fill_manual("", values = c("red", "blue")) +
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(legend.position = c(.8, .8))

})

zz[[3]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks-- I'd prefer to do it without any package (just base R+ggplot2). dplyr acceptable if absolutely necessary, e.g. to select columns, though you don't seem to have gone that way anyway. Could your answer be adapted for this?

Comment: @MobeusZoom - `data.table` package is really only used to take the data from a list into a format suitable for plotting. You can replace that step with something like `dt <- rbind(
data.frame(id = "iris0", iris0),
data.frame(id = "iris1", iris1)
data.frame(id = "iris2", iris2)
)`.  You're free to modify the rest of the answer into whatever specific functions suit your fancy. The crux of the solution here is 1) getting disparate data.frames into one object and 2) building a flexible solution to iterate over the permutations of those data you care about.